# Excel - Return value, after cell has been matched, between headers

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

[image: Snapshot]

Here I am once again, asking for help on this great community.
I hope I can retribute as much as you did someday.

The 4th column (D) in the picture is the expected output.

This is how I put the problem:

- If a number is negative / or has an A (number in the A row is always negative);

  - Use MATCH to check if there is a correspondent (positive) number in the range (between headers);
  - If there is a MATCH output the value of the ID (1st column) of the F that has been matched, and then, output the ID of the A that has been matched
- If not, do nothing or place a 0.

The problems are:

- It needs to loop, because the negative value can come after the positive one;
- The search must be contained between headers.

I've tried to modify and create my own solutions from the tips and codes of the other questions I've placed, but with no success..

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pasting this into the immediate window of the VBE and hitting enter:

```
Names.Add "i", "=$A$1:$A$12": _
Names.Add "v", "=$B$1:$B$12": _
Names.Add "m", "=$D$1:$D$12": _
Names.Add "h", [IF({1},LOOKUP(ROW(i),ROW(i)/(v=INDEX(v,1))))]: _
Names.Add "l", [IF({1},LOOKUP(ROW(i),ROW(i)/(v=INDEX(v,1)),FREQUENCY(-ROW(i),IF(v=INDEX(v,1),-ROW(i),0))-1))]: _
[m]=[IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(v,h,,l),"=-"&v),CONCATENATE("=",ADDRESS(ROW(i),COLUMN(i),4),"&"" AND ""&INDEX(",ADDRESS(h+1,COLUMN(i)),":",ADDRESS(h+l,COLUMN(i)),",MATCH(-",ADDRESS(ROW(v),COLUMN(v),4),",",ADDRESS(h+1,COLUMN(v)),":",ADDRESS(h+l,COLUMN(v)),",0))"),"")]: _
Names("h").Delete: _
Names("l").Delete
```

The output for the example data in the question is:

```
D5  =A5&" AND "&INDEX($A$2:$A$6,MATCH(-B5,$B$2:$B$6,0))
D11 =A11&" AND "&INDEX($A$11:$A$12,MATCH(-B11,$B$11:$B$12,0))
```

*Note*: This method uses named arrays to store intermediate results for header positions `h` and section lengths `l` and takes around 3-4 secs when the range names `i` (id), `v` (value) and `m` (match) are extended to 40,000 rows. A simpler formula for this is possible but it would be very inefficient to fill down on large data sets.

Comment: Yay! I was hoping the formula master would come up with something that didn't require a full-blown VBA solution. How does the `-ROW(i)` work in the `FREQUENCY` function to check the next header occurrence (I see that it does make the array for the lengths, but don't know what `-ROW(i)` means for the data array)?

Comment: Damn, this site is full of geniuses! lori_m, I've gotta send you a cake or something for all the help you've given me! Trully appreciated!!

Comment: I'm glad this helped, it took a while to figure out and was an interesting challenge using functions only - a VBA solution would definitely be easier to follow but probably also a lot longer. @Zairja: The `-` in front of the ROW ensures that the frequency counts are in the same rows as the header in the output array.

Comment: I missed a condition when I asked this, I am sorry =/ If you think you can give a quick look here, it'd be awesome: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936892/excel-return-value-after-cell-has-been-matched-between-headers-v2 . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is the formula I would use. Note that you'll have to explicitly reference the ranges for the headers. You may want to define named ranges to avoid typos and to ease readability. This formula would be put into `D2` (fill-drag to `D6`).

`=IFERROR(IF(B2<0,INDEX($A$2:$A$6,MATCH(B2*-1,$B$2:$B$6,0),1) & " AND " & A2,""),"")`

**How it works:** The `IFERROR` is just to catch the `#NA` when there's no match. If the value `B2` is negative (less than 0), then return the value in the first column of a row with a matching positive value. We use absolute references for the `INDEX` and `MATCH` since we don't want to look in `A3:A7`, `A4:A8`, etc. when the formula gets dragged down into the other cells. Only the value being compared and its corresponding ID should be relative (`A2`/`B2`), since we want that to change for each row.

Here's how it looks. Keep in mind that since my values are from `A1:B6` my formula would be changed to `INDEX($A$1:$A$6...MATCH(B1*-1,$B$1:$B:$6,0)...`

[image: XL]

Comment: Thanks, that works great. However, I really needed to automate the headers part, since I have over 40.000 rows and defining them one by one would take ages

Comment: How familiar are you with VBA?

Comment: I'll see about updating my answer with a VBA solution that's simple enough to understand and change for your needs. I'm sure it's possible with formulas, but I can't think of a way that would make it easier than VBA. Hopefully someone else steps up to the bat, since I'm just an unreliable volunteer like most here on SO! In the meantime, I suggest thinking about the general algorithm for your problem. Would working on a solution save you more time than doing it manually? Is this a one-time operation or will you have to work with more data with the same format in the future?

Comment: Thanks for help Zairja! It would be a monthly work, but the headers wouldn't be in the same place every month and would be in different amounts. That's why automating it would be valuable. Write it the way it's easier for you and I'll dig on the internet if I don't understand something.