# Excel - Return value, after cell has been matched, between headers - V2

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

[image: Example]

This Question is a continuation to the one I posted before at:
[Excel - Return value, after cell has been matched, between headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884850/excel-return-value-after-cell-has-been-matched-between-headers/)

**As before (and more):**

• If a number is negative:

• Use MATCH to check if there is a correspondent (positive) number in the range (between headers) **AND 'IDX' is the same**;

• If there is a MATCH output the value of the ID (1st column) of the F that has been matched, and then, output the ID of the negative value that has been matched ;

• If not, do nothing.

**The problems are:**

• It needs to loop, because the negative value can come after the positive one;

• The search must be contained between headers AND the idx must be the same. I think the image I uploaded is clear, hopefuly.

I've tried modifying the previous answer from lori_m, adding a new variable and condition but everything just went caput:

```
Names.Add "i", "=$A$1:$A$12": _
Names.Add "v", "=$B$1:$B$12": _
Names.Add "m", "=$D$1:$D$12": _
Names.Add "h", [IF({1},LOOKUP(ROW(i),ROW(i)/(v=INDEX(v,1))))]: _
Names.Add "l", [IF({1},LOOKUP(ROW(i),ROW(i)/(v=INDEX(v,1)),FREQUENCY(-ROW(i),IF(v=INDEX(v,1),-ROW(i),0))-1))]: _
[m]=[IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(v,h,,l),"=-"&v),CONCATENATE("=",ADDRESS(ROW(i),COLUMN(i),4),"&"" AND ""&INDEX(",ADDRESS(h+1,COLUMN(i)),":",ADDRESS(h+l,COLUMN(i)),",MATCH(-",ADDRESS(ROW(v),COLUMN(v),4),",",ADDRESS(h+1,COLUMN(v)),":",ADDRESS(h+l,COLUMN(v)),",0))"),"")]: _
Names("h").Delete: _
Names("l").Delete
```

I am very appreciated for all the help.

Comment: Questions should stand alone. Please edit this question to include everything which is relevant to answering it.

Comment: Even though I referenced to another question, I've written as if it's a new one.

Comment: Do you have Excel 2007 / 2010? If so I have a formula that will do this for you.

Comment: Yes, I am using Excel 2010! (:

Comment: If you want to adjust the previous method i posted you could add a name `Formula` to refer to `=Concatenate(...)` and then add more conditions using `[IF(COUNTIFS(...),Formula)]` otherwise you'll hit the 255 char limit. However it's probably better with large amounts of data to move to a VBA solution using dictionaries, I'll try and add one when I've got a sec.

Comment: Thanks for the update lori_m. There's no need to waste your time on this, thank you! Even though it's no the prettiest function it does its work :p

Comment: Actually, do you think it's possible for you to try via VBA, please? If that isn't too much trouble, of course. Thanks

Comment: I've added some code below, it should be quite easy to add extra conditions if needed. This is much more efficient on large data sets, where formula based solutions can really struggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some VBA code for this, it takes around 0.4s on 40,000 rows:

```
Public Sub MatchVals()

    Dim Arr As Variant, dic As Object, v As Variant, Match() As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, n As Long

    Arr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value2
    Set dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    n = UBound(Arr)

    ReDim Match(1 To n, 1 To 1) As String
    k = n
    For i = n To 1 Step -1
        If Arr(i, 3) <> Arr(1, 3) Then
            dic.Add Arr(i, 3) & "|" & Arr(i, 2), i
        Else
            For j = i + 1 To k
                If Arr(j, 3) < 0 Then
                    v = dic(-Arr(j, 3) & "|" & Arr(j, 2))
                    If Not IsEmpty(v) Then
                        Match(v, 1) = Arr(v, 1) & " AND " & Arr(j, 1)
                    End If
                End If
                k = i - 1
            Next j
            dic.RemoveAll
        End If
    Next i

    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        .Offset(0, .Columns.Count).Resize(, 1).Value2 = Match
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks lori_m. There were some functions that I wasn't familiar it, but Google always helps. I'm getting a type mismatch at `v = dic(-Arr(j, 3) & "|" & Arr(j, 2))` , still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Ok, I corrected the code and it's working as it should. I changed it to: 
`For j = i + 1 To k
            If Arr(j, 3) < 0 Then
                v = dic(-Arr(j, 3) & "|" & Arr(j, 2))
                If Not IsEmpty(v) Then
                    Match(v, 1) = Arr(v, 1) & "^" & Arr(j, 1)
                End If
            End If` Now I need to figure out the new date criteria: (http://i.imgur.com/vyf5S.png) . My guess is I'd need to add it to the Variant?

Comment: For the date condition, try inserting an extra condition `If Not Isempty(v) Then If Arr(j, 4) <= Arr(v, 4) Then` and add an extra End If. BTW good job adapting the code

Comment: I just changed <= to >=, since it was doing the reverse operation. Thank you so much lori, finally it's working as it should on the test file. Off to the real file and see how it goes (:

Comment: Good luck! There's nearly always further complications to problems that seemed straightforward at first sight - as demonstrated in your series of posts so far. That's what makes it interesting :)

Comment: Indeed, it escalated pretty quickly! lol I had to add a `On Error Resume Next`before `next i`, otherwise I'd be getting `Run-time error '457'
 This key is already associated with an element of this collection`. Thank you once again for everything lori, good luck to you, too!